# Update blob content type in azure cdn using rest

Tags: c#, rest, azure-blob-storage, azure-cdn

I have integrated `azure cdn` and have a lot of `pdf` files uploaded, but all of them have `octet-stream` content type, because initially I haven't used `x-ms-blob-content-type`, now I have fixed it setting

```
 headers.Add("x-ms-blob-content-type", "application/pdf");
```

So the new files are uploaded in proper content type.
My question is about all the pdf files which have been uploaded before the fixing.
I want to change their content type to `application/pdf`.
Is there a way to do that using rest api?

I have found a way to change it using azure storage explorer, but there are a lot of pdfs in the cloud so I cannot change all of them manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are going to want to loop through blobs in the container and if the extension is .pdf then you want to set the content type to "application/pdf".

Code below should point you in the right direction.

```
      // Storage credentials
        StorageCredentials credentials = new StorageCredentials("accName", "keyValue");
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(credentials, true);
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("theContainer");

        // Continuation Token
        BlobContinuationToken token = null;

        do
        {

            var results = await container.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(null, true, BlobListingDetails.All,
                null, token, null, null);

            // Cast blobs to type CloudBlockBlob
            var blobs = results.Results.Cast<CloudBlockBlob>().ToList();

            foreach (var blob in blobs)
            {
                if (Path.GetExtension(blob.Uri.AbsoluteUri) == ".pdf")
                {
                    blob.Properties.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                }

                await blob.SetPropertiesAsync();
            }

        } while (token != null);
```

Comment: I think it will work fine, but I have to use rest api instead of .net library, do you know how to reach the same result using `rest api`, or do you know if property change supposes to delete the blob and upload it again?

Comment: Well i found this and it can be done. The api contains a ListBlobs and SetProperties endpoint. Look at this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/blob-service-rest-api

Comment: thanks a lot, I think this is the way I should go 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/set-blob-properties

Comment: Yes exactly you've got it.